# After cpanel backup restore magento 2 I do not get it work

Tags: magento2, backup, cpanel, not-found

**Picture 1:**
After the backup restore at cpanel of my mangento 2 webshop because I changed hosting provider, www.takoda.online now shows usually normal like this.

**Picture 2:**
But when I hit any link on this frontpage I get anywhere this 'not found' page, so somewhere there is something wrong, can't figure out what

I did have made the permission all 777 just to be sure that is not the problem.

I do have multiple store views.

Anyone got any idea what I have to check or set up properly to be sure that a backup that I have restored manually?

I have linked the database already.

Thanks a lot
Alain

[image: Usually not always after the backup restore at cpanel of my mangento 2 webshop because I changed hosting provider, www.takoda.online now shows]

[image: But when I hit any link on this frontpage I get anywhere this not found page, so somewhere there is something wrong, can't figure out what]

Comment: Hey man! That sucks,
Have you tried to re-index and stuff? 
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: Issue with Mod-Rewrite or .htaccess missing  at magento project folder . Check all are open with index.php http://takoda.online/index.php/en/all-products.html

Answer (score 0):

Solved it

It indeed was the htaccess issue, it didn't copy the htaccess

So I had manually copy the content to the new htaccess and it did work

Thank You